# SQL Error: ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file (block # )

Tags: oracle

I was getting an error while trying to insert the data from a backup table.

```
SQL Error: ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UND_TBS'
30036. 00000 -  "unable to extend segment by %s in undo tablespace '%s'"
```

To solve this issue, I have creted a new empty datafile to the respective path.
After that I am getting the below given error while trying to do any select/delete operation.

```
Error at Command Line:1 Column:0
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file  (block # )
ORA-01110: data file 82: '/pathOfDataFile/my_newly_created_datafile.dbf'
ORA-27072: File I/O error
Additional information: 7
Additional information: 16578
01115. 00000 -  "IO error reading block from file %s (block # %s)"
*Cause:    Device on which the file resides is probably offline
*Action:   Restore access to the device
```

I checked the status of the file which is `ONLINE`.
Any idea how can I fix this error?

Comment: On the operating system level, is the file online and readable?

Comment: I checked the status with `select * from dba_data_files` and is found to be `ONLINE`

Comment: That's what oracle believes, but you need to check the reality.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Log into that machine (putty is your friend) and do an `ls -l /pathOfDataFile/my_newly_created_datafile.dbf` (assuming Linux or another Unix-like operating system)

Comment: who is the owner of the file? Should be `oracle oinstall` usually.

Comment: Sorry.. its like `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root system `

Comment: Check the other database files, do they have the same permission? `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root system` seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: No, they are having `-rw-r-----    1 oracle   dba `

Comment: Before you try anything else, make a backup. Then, and only then, you can try to change owner and permissions of this file, or to copy it to another location (just to see if there are any errors on the OS level) etc.

Comment: Ok. What to do in this case? Is this the root cause for the above problem?

Comment: One more thing comes to my mind: check that the whole path to the file is readable for oracle. Maybe the parent directory or another directory up to root is not accessable for the OS user `oracle`.

Comment: But there is no issue with any other data files in the same dir.

Comment: OK, in that case, is the file system full? Check it with `df`

Comment: It shows `99%` as used